# Where/how to add a page title to a section (listing)

Tags: sections

I have a number of pages/sections (listings) in either channels or structures. Each page/section (listing) will have a heading that displays an editable title of each page/section.

Should I be able to set this up so the client can edit the title of each section from *within* that section page in admin? I'm not seeing where to do that. Or do I have to put that field in another place, not within my section? Like in a global settings section that provides editing of each of my sections/pages?

For example, if the page heading says 'Our Projects', but my client wants to be able to change it to 'About Our Amazing Projects' or whatever, where is the best place to put that? I see a 'Name' field for each section, but I'm not sure if that is the appropriate place for it.

Comment: Are you referring to the Title field of an Entry or do you mean the name of the Section itself?

Comment: The title of the page/section that gets seen by end users of the site. I updated my question to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you're asking is how to manage content for listing/index page that would pull in entries in a channel. Like the main index page for a blog that shows a list of recent blog entries. Or an "Our Projects" page that's the parent for project detail child pages.

The way I like to do this is create a Single section called "Blog Index" or "Our Projects." You can then use that Blog Index entry to manage the page title or any other content like a hero image or SEO metadata.

[image]

Then make sure you check the "Show the Title field" option under it's entry types (where you setup the sections fields).

[image]

If you are on the Blog index page, you can use `{{ entry.title }}` in template.

Or if you are on another page, like a blog entry, and you want to pull the Blog Index title, you can do something like this:

```
{% set blogIndex = craft.entries.section('blogIndex').one() %}

{{ blogIndex.title }}
```

I prefer this to using globals because it also handles my settings for the URI route and template instead of relying on file-based template routes.

I think it's possible to pull information about a section/channel/structure like it's name. But the real downside to this approach is it requires the client to change settings in parts of the control panel you don't need or want them poking around in. Those are settings, not content.